# how to use javascript filter using an id from html element from another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to find a way to pass the id of the h4 element to SpecificPost component so I can filter it and only view the post with that specific id.

component 1

```
 render() {
    var reversedPosts = Object.assign([], this.props.posts);
    reversedPosts = reversedPosts.reverse();

    return (
    <div>
      <div>
      {reversedPosts.map((item) =>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="twelve columns">
              <h4 className="hoverh1" Id={item.Id} onClick={this.props.openedSpecificPost} >{item.question}   <a className="tag">{item.postType}</a>  </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      )}
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

component 2 is rendered when h4 is clicked and it will show the post that was clicked on.

```
const allPosts = Object.assign([], this.props.posts);
    const Id = allPosts.filter(function(item) {
      return item.Id == (need to grab the id from the h4 element);
    })
```

[My Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app232323?embed=1&file=Posts.js)
look in the SpecificPost component and Posts component. On the app press newest and you can see the posts, and when you click one I have it set so it will filter a post with an id less than 100 just so it runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a wrapper function which will call `this.props.openedSpecificPost` with the current item id:

```
<h4
  className="hoverh1"
  Id={item.Id}
  onClick={_ => this.props.openedSpecificPost(item.Id)}
>
  {item.question}
  <a className="tag">{item.postType}</a>
</h4>
```

Comment: So I would need to put the filter logic inside of index.js in the App component?

Comment: Maybe. Or you can just pass the `item`.

Comment: It's a argument named `_`. When you don't need an arrow function to receive arguments you can do that, or use parethesis `() => { ... }`.